# how to create custom front end on eclipse che?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-che

I read eclipse che is build by using api rest on server side and we can build a custom frontend over it does anyone know how to do it ?
i'm not fqmilliar with this environnement... 
thanks for your help

Comment: Eclipse Che is a completely different product from Eclipse RCP.

Comment: thank greg apologize for that but when i'm loonking for an answer i always find this link....

Comment: Eclipse RCP is a much older product (originally released in 2001) than Eclipse Che (released in 2016). The majority of articles you will find will be about Eclipse RCP.

Answer (score 1):

There is a great talk by Sergii Kabashniuk (one of the Eclipse Che core developer) on "swapping IDE's" in Che. This may give you basic idea on how this works:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TJp6ZhZeC5c

And if you have any further questions, you can come to https://mattermost.eclipse.org/ to the "Eclipse Che" channel to talk directly to devs ;-) Or write an e-mail to eclipse-che@redhat.com
Radim